# Is there a shortcut for clearing .Rhistory in Visual Studio

Tags: r, visual-studio, rtvs

I am starting to prefer *Visual Studio with RTVS* over *RStudio* because of Visual Studio's great find-and-replace facilities.  My only gripe is that it often finds things in my `.Rhistory` file when I'm trying to search through my code.

**Is there a shortcut key for deleting the contents of `.Rhistory` when using R Tools for Visual Studio?**

I am using RTVS v1.0.30321.1407 with Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell RTVS not to keep your history around by going to R Tools -> Options -> Always save history -> set to `FALSE`.

You can also delete an existing .RHistory file if you don't want to keep it around. It's just a regular file; if you have a project loaded, it'll be in your project directory.

Other than that, it's a good idea to specify a file type when doing a search through multiple files. That will stop .RHistory from showing up in the first place.